# Can a single kubernetes job contain multiple pods with different parallelism definitions?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-jobs

I have a batch job which breaks down in 3 tasks that each depend on the previous finishing before they can start:

1. Run a single pod
2. Run N pods in parallel (`.spec.completions` = `.spec.parallelism` = N)
3. Run M pods in parallel (`.spec.completions` = `.spec.parallelism` = M)

Each task has different resource requirements (CPU/MEM/STORAGE). Currently, I start job #1, when it finishes it runs a `kubectl` command to start job #2, and so on to job #3. I have 3 separate jobs.

Can I define a single job for these 3 tasks?

Maybe something like this:

1. Run single pod for task #1
2. Define init container on task #2 to wait for task #1 to finish
3. Run N pods for task #2 using `.spec.completions`
4. Define init container on task # to wait for task #2 to finish
5. Run M pods for task #3 using a different `.spec.completions` appropriate for task #3

It's not clear to me if I can define separate `.spec.parallelism` and `.spec.completions` for different pods under the same job. And if I can define separate init containers to delay the start of the later tasks.

This may all require a more complete workflow engine like Argo (which we don't yet have available).

Comment: Maybe I don't understand well enough but Job can contain only one Pod definition (`template`) so the answer is no and it doesn't depend on whether you want to set a different parallelism or not. It is just no.

Comment: Kubernetes only offers a `work queue` paralellism solution for this use case. See [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#parallel-jobs). Let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: @MatusDubrava That's a sufficient answer if you want to post it, I thought the answer might be no. Sege the work queue isn't a solution because the pods need to have different resource requirements.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect use case for Airflow. :)  If you're on GCP, for example, you may try Composer. https://cloud.google.com/composer

Comment: I believe we looked at Airflow (and certainly other workflow engines), the problem with almost every one of them across the board was that they demanded administrator privileges in the kubernetes cluster. Our cluster is a mulit-tenant environment where those permissions cannot be given out without having a lot of knock on effects. But in general, yes, a good workflow engine is a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kubernetes Job Controller creates a pod based on the single pod template in the Job spec. *So No you can't have multiple pods in a Job*.

But kubernetes is an extensible system and you can define your own [Custom Resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/) and write a controller like Job controller which supports multiple pod templates with different parallelism.

Answer (score 3):

I just figured out a way to do this.

The yaml file supports multiple files. So you can append multiple job definitions under a single yaml file, using `---` as the deliminator.

Here is an example:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: ge-test-job
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ge-test-1
        image: improbableailab/model-free
        command: ["perl", "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print 1"]
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: 200Mi
            cpu: 1000m
          requests:
            memory: 50Mi
            cpu: 500m
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /jaynes-mounts
          name: ge-pvc
      restartPolicy: Never
      volumes:
        - name: ge-pvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: ge-pvc
  backoffLimit: 4
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 10
---
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: ge-test-job-2
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: ge-test-2
          image: improbableailab/model-free
          command: ["perl", "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print 1"]
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: 200Mi
              cpu: 1000m
            requests:
              memory: 50Mi
              cpu: 500m
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /jaynes-mounts
              name: ge-pvc
      restartPolicy: Never
      volumes:
        - name: ge-pvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: ge-pvc
  backoffLimit: 4
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 10
```

Now if you run

```sh
❯ kubectl apply -f job.yaml
job.batch/ge-test-job created
job.batch/ge-test-job-2 created
```

Comment: Technically that creates multiple jobs, but it's a useful addition to this question, it may be what some people are actually looking for.